# Run a windows batch file periodically passing different variables each time

Tags: python, powershell

I have a windows batch file that outputs a file and takes in 4 variables.

```
batch.exe output_file.txt -1 dummy_variable1 -2 dummy_variable2 -3 dummy_variable3 -4 dummy_variable4
```

I want to run this command periodically, say after 1 minute, passing in a different output file name and different variables. Is there a way to do this without manually having to type the command and input the output file name and variables each time? For example, edit the command in a script and then echo it to the terminal each time to run it.

Comment: [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2917778/9267296). If you use an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) you can pass variables from within your python script to the batch file.

Comment: You can use the combination of the time module and using an f-string.

Comment: I wrote a powershell function that would make this pretty easy, starting with the parameter list in a csv file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230306/how-to-combine-a-template-with-a-csv-file-in-powershell

Comment: Windows should have some `Task Scheduler` similar to `cron` on LInux which let you run script periodically - and in this script you should get different values and run your batch.